# How can I remove a list item so it does not appear on form submit?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a list to select individuals and add them to a list, but then I want the option of removing them from the list if accidentally selected. When I click remove, they do disappear from the list, but they still appear in the database when I submit the form. What am I doing wrong?
Here's what I've got:

```
      var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() {
          var div = this.parentElement;
          div.remove(div);
        };
      }
```

I originally had a display = none thing and realized it was just hiding, then I tried this remove and it still appears in the database after submit.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean your data too. If you're using input data from the form it should be ok:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target).entries()));
});

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.remove(div);
  };
}
```

```html
<form>
<ul>
<li>List item with hidden input <input type="hidden" name="some" value="value"><button class="close" type="button">Close</button></li>
</ul>
<button>Submit with list item and without</button>
</form>
```